# Post Survey on our company facebook page using PHP SDK

Tags: facebook

Our company deals with various online contests. As a part of functionality we need to post questions with fixed options to our facebook page periodically. Any idea about how to implement this using facebook api?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on how to ask questions here. You may also want to read some of the questions posted here to get a feel for how this site works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using graph api. The url will be {page_id}/questions. You need to pass the question as a string and options as an array.

Below code helps you to do that using facebook PHP SDK:

```
$question = $_POST['question'];
    $options = array($_POST['option1'], $_POST['option2'], $_POST['option3']);
    $api_params = array(
        'question' => $question,
        'options' => $options,
        'allow_new_options' => false
    );
   $url=$facebook->api($_POST['select-page'] . '/questions', 'POST', $api_params);
```

[Visit this link](http://bit.ly/yxTYas) for demo and code samples

Comment: What if I want to post a survey to wall (/me/feed) or something similar??